# How do I install a driver for a Kodak esp 3250 printer?

Tags: printing

First my system: pentium 4 -don't remember the speed-, 1g ram, dual boot to separate physical drives, Fdos and Lubuntu 12.1

second my lan: I have four computers operating for the same printer.

1. Intel quad core i5, 4g ram, running Windows 7 64 bit, printer connected and shared from here. Kodak ESP 3250
2. Gateway 17" laptop running Windows 7 32bit
3. Asus tablet (small laptop) running Lumbutu 12.1
4. My dual boot system running Fdos and Lubuntu 12.1

The problem:
I downloaded c2esp_25c-1_i386.deb, tried to install it using DEBI Package Installer, it loads the files, looks for cups driver and ends with an error:
"Dependancy is not satisfiable: libcupsdriver1 (>=1.4.0)"
What do I do now? Is there some place that I can get the correct cups driver?

further information:
The Asus tablet was running Ubuntu 12.1 (very slowly and with a few crashes) and could print from the lan printer with no problems. Is there something in Ubuntu that can be loaded into Lubuntu?

Comment: If no one knows how to get a Kodak ESP 3250 printer to work on Lubuntu 12.1 can you at least direct me to some place or someone who might?

Answer (score 2):

I got this working but it is more than installing a Debian driver.

1. I downloaded the c2esp26.tar.gz file and the install instructions
2. Following the instructions I used the synaptic package manager to install the "Optional packages needed" except 1 that was not available - "libcupsdriver1-dev".
3. I then used archive manager to extract the files in the c2esp26.tar.gz file
4. Following the installation instructions I used term (right clicking the Tar file allows you to open term in that folder) to "make" the package usable.
5. Then to install them I used "sudo make install" in the same term window.
6. I closed the term with "exit" and opened the "system tools - printers" configuration window.
7. I selected add, network printer, windows printer via SAMBA
8. I then entered the name of the host computer (the one with the printer connected)
9. I hit the Browse button and clicked down to hilite the printer.
10. hit forward and selected the driver from the list for the Kodak 3250 esp printer driver.
11. The drivers were found and installed and I printed the test page.
    There is a 15 - 20 second lag between hitting the "print" command and when it starts to print so under "properties" I adjusted the resolution to 300 x 1200 instead of the default 600 x 1200.

There you go. It was a lot of frustrating doing and redoing trying to find the way to get Lubuntu 12.10 to work the network printer but it will be easier for the next person.